# Form generator with CRUD operations for Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

Some related questions have been posted on this topic, but for Wicket specifically they date back to almost a decade ago. What are some modern day solutions to creating a table (data pulled from a database) with CRUD operations in Wicket similarly to the screenshot below.

[image]

Note the above example was created using Wicket RAD which has not been updated since 2010

Answer (score 0):

Check [Apache Isis](https://isis.apache.org/).

In Isis you define a Pojo/Model and it generates both UI (Wicket) and REST (RestEasy) frontends for you. It is quite advanced but also it learning curve is a bit steep.